# Convert WebVTT file from Youtube to plain text

Tags: bash, awk, youtube-dl, webvtt

I am downloading WebVTT files from youtube using youtube-dl.

A typical file looks like this:

```
WEBVTT
Kind: captions
Language: en

00:00:00.730 --> 00:00:05.200 align:start position:0%

[Applause]

00:00:05.200 --> 00:00:05.210 align:start position:0%
[Applause]


00:00:05.210 --> 00:00:11.860 align:start position:0%
[Applause]
hi<00:00:06.440><c> I'm</c><00:00:07.440><c> here</c><00:00:07.740><c> to</c><00:00:08.160><c> talk</c><00:00:08.429><c> to</c><00:00:09.019><c> share</c><00:00:10.019><c> an</c><00:00:10.469><c> idea</c><00:00:10.820><c> to</c>

00:00:11.860 --> 00:00:11.870 align:start position:0%
hi I'm here to talk to share an idea to


00:00:11.870 --> 00:00:15.890 align:start position:0%
hi I'm here to talk to share an idea to
communicate<00:00:12.920><c> but</c><00:00:13.920><c> what</c><00:00:14.790><c> is</c><00:00:14.940><c> communication</c>

00:00:15.890 --> 00:00:15.900 align:start position:0%
communicate but what is communication
```

I would like to get a text file with this:

```
hi I'm here to talk to share an idea to
communicate but what is communication
```

Using code I found online, I got this:

```
cat output.vtt | sed "s/^[0-9]*[0-9\:\.\ \>\-]*//g" | grep -v "^WEBVTT\|^Kind: cap\|^Language" | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="\n\n+"; RS="\n\n" }NR>=2{ print }' > dialogues.txt
```

But it is far from perfect. I get a lot of useless spaces, and all the sentences are displayed twice. Would you mind helping me? Somebody asked a similar question before but the answer submitted did not work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something similar to this:

```
sed -e '1,4d' -E -e '/^$|]|>$|%$/d' output.vtt | awk '!seen[$0]++' > dialogues.txt
```

- `sed` removes the first 4 lines
- `sed` then deletes any blank lines, or ones that contain `]`, or end in `>`, `%`.
- `awk` removes duplicate lines.

**Result**:

```
hi I'm here to talk to share an idea to
communicate but what is communication
```

You might have to tweak it a bit, although it should result in more along the lines of what you want.

Comment: This removes all new lines after the first four (which may be intended, but wasn't what I wanted), but more importantly, it doesn't seem to answer the question as it leaves all of the timestamps in.

Comment: careful though with that regex - sometimes those damn lyric files may embed html-esque tags without a duplicate line for u to throw away (and i had to deal with unicode on top of all that)

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following in a single `awk` itself.

```
awk 'FNR<=4 || ($0 ~ /^$|-->|\[|\]|</){next} !a[$0]++'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation now for above code.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program here.
FNR<=4 || ($0 ~ /^$|-->|\[|\]|</){        ##Checking condition if line number is less than 4 OR having spaces or [ or ] or --> then go next line.
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
  }
!a[$0]++                                  ##Creating an array whose index is $0 and increment its value with 1 with condition that it should NOT be already present in array a, which means it will give only 1 value of each line.
'  Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Good all in one solution; some explanation would be nice +1

Comment: Sure, thanks for encouragement, I have added explanation now.

Comment: This almost works, but it removes all new lines (which may be intended, I'm not sure, but wasn't what I wanted) and most importantly, it removes all duplicate lines, which is a serious problem in, for example, subtitles for music, where only the first instance of a chorus would be kept.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze the pattern of your .vtt file, basically you want to keep every 8th line starting at line 10. So the algorithm is to delete the first 2 lines, then keep every 8th line:

```
$ cat output.vtt | sed '1,2 d' | awk 'NR%8==0'

[Applause]
hi I'm here to talk to share an idea to
communicate but what is communication
```

- `sed '1,2 d'` deletes range from line 1 to line 2
- `awk 'NR%8==0'` prints every 8th line

If you want to further filter out the "[...]" lines, then you can add another grep command such as `grep -v '^\[.*\]$'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to:

- Remove the first 4 lines
- Remove all timestamp lines
- *Keep* the empty lines between subtitles

I managed to do this with the following single `sed` command:

```
sed -En '1,4d;/^[0-9].:[0-9].:[0-9].+$/!p' input.vtt > output.txt
```

If like me, you need to do this often and you're using Bash, you could also convert this to a Bash function:

```
function vtt_to_txt() {
    sed -En '1,4d;/^[0-9].:[0-9].:[0-9].+$/!p' "$1" > "$2"
}
```

This would allow you to simply call the function like so at any time:

```
vtt_to_text input.vtt output.txt
```